# What is the current status of Stirling engine-based radioisotope generator technology?

Tags: power, rtg

[@Heopps' cool answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30870/12102) to the question *Any proposed missions to explore the black liquid on Titan? Technical challenges?* has an interesting line:

> [ASRG generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Stirling_radioisotope_generator) was planned as compact energy source but its development didn't end well enough.

which makes me wonder just how well it ended.

The Wikipedia article for the [Advanced Stirling radioisotope generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Stirling_radioisotope_generator) says:

> Despite termination of the ASRG flight development contract in 2013, NASA continues a small investment testing by private companies. Flight-ready Stirling-based units are expected by 2028.

which is still so far in the future that it seems speculative.

The downside of the technology versus thermocouple-based heat-to-electricity conversion includes things like added complexity and moving parts, but I assume the upside is a higher efficiency which means for a given power output either a smaller quantity of a given isotope can be used or a less-effective alternate radioisotope can be selected.

> The energy conversion process used by an ASRG is about four times more efficient than in previous radioisotope systems to produce a similar amount of power, and **allows it to use about one quarter of the plutonium-238 as other similar generators.** (emphasis added)

So I'd like to ask; what is the current status of Stirling engine-based radioisotope generator technology? Has the technology fallen by the wayside in lieu of solar panels, thermocouple-based RTGs and kilopower fission reactors, or is this technology coming along nicely and may indeed be ready in 2028, or even sooner?

Comment: Any NASA technology being worked on usually has reports on NTRS: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/ - I’d search there. As far as I know, work on Stirling engines is still ongoing.

Comment: @hmode thanks, I'll take a look and see how far I can get. For the purposes of this question the work would not have be necessarily associated with NASA, substantial progress being made at any agency or company would count.

Comment: "1-W Stirling RPS is being developed for notional surface missions" -[Nasa, October 2018](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20190001014.pdf). With system testing planned in 2020 I would assume the development is coming along nicely, although this is a topic which is properly underfunded.
[Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_ylo=2018&q=stirling+engine+radioisotope&btnG=) is full of recent papers (2018-2019) about the technology

Comment: You've only been here 45 days but you are really @GittingGud at this! Why not write that up as an answer? ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't Stirling engines degrade over time as they wear down? You want your RTG to last, right?

Comment: @RangaRutiserSundar that may be one of the reasons these are still in development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this presentation](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20190001014.pdf) from October 2018 held by NASA employee Scott Wilson, NASA is currently working on a radioisotope power system (RPS) using Stirling engines as the generator.

The RPS is supposed to be a low power electricity source of 1-10W DC, with a 1 watt demonstrator/prototype being currently worked on.

The development goals for the RPS is a life time of 20 years with proposed use in small spacecraft missions, especially for notional surface Moon and Mars missions.

**The Roadmap currently is:**
2018 - Initial Demonstration
2019 - Mature Fidelity
2020 - System Testing

---

Additionally [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_ylo=2018&q=stirling%20engine%20radioisotope&btnG=) has several recent publications on this topic, from which a lot are from NASA.